# Problem with establishing connection to internet

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, vmware

I am unable to reach any web server from ubuntu VM ware on macOS host.

Host: MacOS --> internet connection is fine
Guest: Ubuntu --> internet connection not fine

#### Ubuntu version

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

#### Ifconfig

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.010.11  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:09:48:52:9b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 50178  bytes 63227601 (63.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50178  bytes 63227601 (63.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

#### Network Manager Status

```
sudo systemctl status network-manager.service 
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-11-19 11:53:22 CET; 10s ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 8622 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 14267)
     Memory: 2.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─8622 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.1865] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.1865] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.1880] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.1881] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.1888] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.1895] manager: (ens33): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <warn>  [1637319202.1900] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.1944] manager: startup complete
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.2162] agent-manager: agent[de5a91ed7bc2b4be,:1.39/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Nov 19 11:53:22 ubuntu NetworkManager[8622]: <info>  [1637319202.2202] modem-manager: ModemManager available
```

#### NS lookup

```
nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

Can someone guide me to trouble shoot this problem and fix it?

---

#### interfaces

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# This is a list of hotpluggable network interfaces.
# They will be activated automatically by the hotplug subsystem.
# auto eth1

# iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

#### netplan

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

#### lshw

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for -----: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
       version: 01
       serial: 00:0c:29:a1:3f:99
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=5.11.0-38-generic duplex=full latency=0 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
```

#### VMWARE network settings

[image]

Comment: Not an Ubuntu problem. The problem is at the VMWare settings.

Comment: You may want to confirm that you've assigned a network device to the VM, as there isn’t one in your `ifconfig` output 

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have added the additional info you have asked, can you please check.

Comment: Thanks for the data. They look fine. Show me `sudo lshw -C network`. Thanks! Have you checked your VMWare network settings as per @ChanganAuto?

Comment: @heynnema please have a look.

Comment: Everything looks fine, except for `ifconfig` doesn't show ens33. I do see docker, and I'm not familiar with docker, but isn't there a config file that needs to be edited to make it work? Somewhere the ens33 device is not being seen. Did you recheck the VMWare network settings?

Comment: @heynnema I have checked everything in vmware settings and everrthing seems ok to me. I have added the screenshot, please check.

Comment: Try Bridged autodetect and see what happens. Use `ifconfig` to see if ens33 shows up after restarting.

Comment: @heynnema yeah I tried this things, but nothing worked.
The adapter wont appear in the config.

Comment: And you checked your docker settings, yes? I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema yes i did.

Comment: The problem got fixed by itself, after a few continuous restarts the DHCP could get the IP established. I have no idea what was the root cause.

I do face the problem now and then. But then restarting it and waiting couple of minutes at DHCP connection establishment step at console loading, finally everything works.